# Intercalate multiple columns when some of those columns must remain in the same row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In *Column A* I have the id of the home team, *B* the name of the home team, *C* the id of the visiting team and in *D* the name of the visiting team:

```
12345       Borac Banja Luka    98765       B36
678910      Panevezys           43214       Milsami
1112131415  Flora               7852564     SJK
1617181920  Magpies             874236551   Dila
```

I want to create a column of ids and another of names but keeping the sequence of who will play with whom:

```
12345       Borac Banja Luka
98765       B36
678910      Panevezys
43214       Milsami
1112131415  Flora
7852564     SJK
1617181920  Magpies
874236551   Dila
```

Currently (the model works) I'm joining the columns with a special character, using flatten and finally split:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(FLATTEN({
                             FILTER(A1:A&"§§§§§"&B1:B,(A1:A<>"")*(B1:B<>"")),
                             FILTER(C1:C&"§§§§§"&D1:D,(C1:C<>"")*(D1:D<>""))
                    }),"§§§§§"))
```

Is there a less archaic and correct approach to working in this type of case?

[Spreadsheet to tests](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1twlYH1f8nYeVDXKHt0XsAk1kjiErm0RNfptyypw4DRc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I do wonder why you consider it "archaic"

Comment: @player0 I wanted to say in terms of using two filters and needing to split with a special character, I understand that my way was very messy and that possibly there would be a better structured way (in this specific case, even more if there were several columns and not just two)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 889 | A | 5687 | C |
| 532 | B | 8723 | D |

Stack up the columns using `{}` and `SORT` them by a `SEQUENCE` of `1,2,1,2`:

```
=SORT({A1:B2;C1:D2},{SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B2));SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1:B2))},1)
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 889 | A |
| 5687 | C |
| 532 | B |
| 8723 | D |

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with function `QUERY`, enter this formula in `F1`:

```
={QUERY((A1:B), "SELECT * WHERE A IS NOT NULL and B IS NOT NULL",1);
QUERY((C1:D), "SELECT * WHERE C IS NOT NULL and D IS NOT NULL",1)}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this option does not generate the necessary sequence for the case.